# how to fetch case insensitive data using SIMILAR TO clause in postgresql jsonb search?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Below query I am using to fetch data. it is giving data.
but i want to use `DxC` to sercah so it should give all dxc related data.

**Current Query:**

```
select count(*) 
from enterprise_1.contacts_master 
where contact_data::json->>'Company' SIMILAR TO ('%(DXC|dxc)%')
```

o/p: 2

**Expected Query**

```
select count(*) 
from enterprise_1.contacts_master 
where contact_data::json->>'Company' SIMILAR TO ('%(DxC)%')
```

current o/p: 0
expected o/p: 2

I don't want to use `ILike`

Comment: What's wrong with `ILIKE`? That won't be slower than `SIMILAR TO`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but can i use `%(DXC|dxc)%` using ILike ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how to use this *~ ? could you please tell me

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search in a case-insensitive manner, then

```
where contact_data::json->>'Company' ILIKE '%DxC%'
```

is exactly what you are looking for.

As ILIKE is case-insensitive, there is no need to provide different versions of the substring. The above will match `dxc`, `DXC`, `dXc` or `Dxc` anywhere in the company string.

If you do want to use a (case insensitive) regular expression, you can use the [`~*` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

```
where contact_data::json->>'Company' ~* 'DxC'
```

`~*` compares based on a regular expression in a case-insensitive manner. The above searches for a substring `'DxC'` anywhere in the company string ignoring upper/lowercase.

Comment: how can i use `*~` withsimilar to ?

Comment: @SangramBadi: you can't - those are two different operators. You either use `similar to` or the regex operator `~*`